# why does lastindexOf() not find the last element

Tags: javascript, substring, lastindexof

I'm trying to extract a sub string from a string with Javascript and have come up with the following: http://jsfiddle.net/bbhbz7r6/1/ for some reason however, .lastindexOf() doesn't find the last occurrence of `<td class="views-field views-field-line-item-title">` but the first one... and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: look Jan's answer. you don't have to do `string.length-start`, you already found the last index at which your init- <td> occurs, so substring from that point to the end of the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually correct. The problem is in the second line which should be

```
var tail = string.substring(start, string.length);
```